# None of my assets working on live site (Laravel 5)

Tags: php, laravel, resources, laravel-5

I've been working on my site locally (my first laravel 5 site, I was using 4.2 previously).

Upon uploading all my files to the live site, I receive a 404 when attempting to grab my resources(app/css, any photos. etc). These are what it looks like (please note I'm using illuminate for my forms and HTML in blade:

```
{!! Html::style(asset('css/app.css')) !!} 
{!! Html::image(asset('images/logo.png')) !!}
```

Again, this works completely fine locally. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `asset` method prefixes that URL with whatever your `app.url` config value is. For example if `config/app.php` has:

```
'url' => 'http://localhost',
```

Then `asset("css/style.css")` will output `http://localhost/css/style.css`

You need to update the `url` value for your live environment. Ideally since this is something that will change between environments, add a new variable to your `.env` file:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

And then update your `config/app.php` to be:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL'),
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5, you can use the normal html link tag to do that. just wrap your assets around a link tag like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
<img src="{{ asset(images/logo.png }}">
```